# Do the limit law proofs in one variable easily extend to multivariable?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have attempted to prove, in $R^3$, the limit law "the limit of a product is the product of the limits" using a similiar style of proof which I have seen done for the single variable proof:

$\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{\alpha}} f\cdot g = \lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{\alpha}} f \cdot\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{\alpha}} g$

**Proof:**

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{\alpha}} f = K$ and $\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{\alpha}} g = L$

$\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{\alpha}} f\cdot g = K \cdot L$

$\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{\alpha}} f\cdot g - K \cdot L = 0$

$\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{\alpha}} f\cdot g - K \cdot L + Kg - Kg + Lf - Lf + KL-KL = 0$

$\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{\alpha}} k(g-L) + L(f-K) + (f-K)(g-Lf) = 0$

Defining $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \epsilon_3$ as:

$\epsilon_1 = \frac{\epsilon}{3+3|K|}$ $\epsilon_2 = \frac{\epsilon}{3+3|L|}$ $\epsilon_3 = \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{3}}$

$\exists \delta_1 > 0$ s.t. $\forall x$ $0 < ||\vec{x} - \vec{a}|| < \delta_1 \implies |g-L| < \epsilon_1$

$\exists \delta_2 > 0$ s.t. $\forall x$ $0 < ||\vec{x} - \vec{a}|| < \delta_2 \implies |f-K| < \epsilon_2$

$\exists \delta_3 > 0$ s.t. $\forall x$ $0 < ||\vec{x} - \vec{a}|| < \delta_3 \implies |g-L| < \epsilon_3$

$\exists \delta_4 > 0$ s.t. $\forall x$ $0 < ||\vec{x} - \vec{a}|| < \delta_4 \implies |f-K| < \epsilon_3$

Let $\delta$ be the min$\{\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3,\delta_4\}$

Then $\forall x$ $||\vec{x} - \vec{a}|| < \delta \implies 0 < ||\vec{x} - \vec{a}|| < \delta_1$, $0 < ||\vec{x} - \vec{a}|| < \delta_2$, $0 < ||\vec{x} - \vec{a}|| < \delta_3$ and $0 < ||\vec{x} - \vec{a}|| < \delta_4 \implies |g-L| < \epsilon_1$, $|f-K| < \epsilon_2$, $|f-K| < \epsilon_3$ and $|g-L| < \epsilon_3$

Thus since $|f \cdot g-K \cdot L| = K(g-L) + L(f-K) + (f-K)(g-L)$

using the triangle inequality

$|f \cdot g-K \cdot L| \leq |K||(g-L)| + |L||(f-K)| + |(f-K)||(g-L)|$

using $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \epsilon_3$

$|f \cdot g-K \cdot L| < \frac{|K| \cdot \epsilon}{3+3|K|} + \frac{|L| \cdot \epsilon}{3+3|L|} + (\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{3}})^2$

$|f \cdot g-K \cdot L| < \frac{|K| \cdot \epsilon}{3(1+|K|)} + \frac{|L| \cdot \epsilon}{3(1+|L|)} +\frac{\epsilon}{3}$

Since $0 \leq \frac{|K|}{1+|K|} \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \frac{|L|}{1+|L|} \leq 1$ we take them as 1, still maintaining the inequality.

$|f \cdot g-K \cdot L| < \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3}$

$|f \cdot g-K \cdot L| < \epsilon$

which proves $\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{\alpha}} f\cdot g = K \cdot L$

proving that $\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{\alpha}} f\cdot g = \lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{\alpha}} f \cdot\lim_{\vec{x} \to \vec{\alpha}} g$

My question is does this proof hold up for $R^3$ in this form? I have read in my textbook that the proofs for the limit laws are similiar in $R^3$ and in $R^2$ so I feel this should suffice, but is anything more needed to prove this limit law? Any help would be appreciated.